# R markdown inline formula (latex) not working

Tags: latex, r-markdown

First time markdown user (and LaTex novice).

I'm trying to insert inline formulas using single $ as I have seen demonstrated in several places, including the [R Markdown Reference Guide](http://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/rmarkdown-reference.pdf) - but it's not working.

```
inline equation test: $x \leq 5 $ not working
```

is simply output as

"inline equation test: $x 5 $ not working"

It works fine using $$ to create a new line, but any tips how to get it working inline would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 18):

And as so often happens, as soon as I ask a question, the answer comes to me.

```
inline equation test: $x \leq 5 $ not working
```

has a space before the closing $ and does not work.

```
inline equation test: $x \leq 5$ not working
```

has the space deleted and works just fine.

Comment: I'm surprised whitespace would matter, but it appears you're right.

Comment: Here's more info on whitespace for inline TeX math mode using in RMarkdown documents: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62918142/2029527