# R Markdown Inline LaTeX Equations: `$` ... `$` vs `\(` ... `\)`

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, pandoc

````
---
title: "esc"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

A. An amount between $5 and $10.  
B. An amount between \$5 and \$10.  
C. An amount between \\$5 and \\$10.    

X. An equation $1 and 1 = 2$.  
Y. An equation \$1 and 1 = 2\$.  
Z. An equation \\$1 and 1 = 2\\$.
````

I've got a similar, but different question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62915849/cant-escape-latex-dollar-sign-in-blogdown). Please comment if I need to add clarification to differences. I'm asking two different questions and hope that's obvious.

Anyways, the output of knitting the .Rmd above is shown below. Why does example `X` properly invoke LaTeX, where example `A` does not? `X` and `A` seem almost identical to me, and I'm left wondering why they both don't transform whatever is inside the dollar signs `$`  into LaTeX text?

I'm aware I could use `\(` and `\)` to replace `$` and `$`. I just want to know why `$` and `$` doesn't properly call LaTeX in my example. It seems arbitray that it works for `X`, but not `A`, although I doubt it's arbitrary.

[image: esc rmd output]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pandoc's manual, under the [*Pandoc's Markdown > Math* section](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#math), probably explains it best:

> Anything between two `$` characters will be treated as TeX math. The opening `$` must have a non-space character immediately to its right, while the closing `$` must have a non-space character immediately to its left, and must not be followed immediately by a digit. Thus, `$20,000 and $30,000` won’t parse as math. If for some reason you need to enclose text in literal `$` characters, backslash-escape them and they won’t be treated as math delimiters.